# How can I speed up indexof in c#?

Tags: c#

Here are two strings:

```
string a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string A="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

The strings have 1500 characters and each character in the string is unique and constant.

When there is an article, I have to get the index in `a` of each character in it. And then return the corresponding index of the character in `A`.

For example:

If the article is "Here is an article", it will return "HERE IS AN ARTICLE".

What I want to do is not just character uppercase. I am not allowed to show the source code, so I can only show an example that is alike to my project. Please excuse this.

The List way:

```
public string Translate(string i)
{
    DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in i)
    {
        int j = a.IndexOf(c);
        if (j != -1)
        {
            SB.Append(A[j]);
        }
        else
        {
            SB.Append(c.ToString());
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Time:" + (DateTime.Now - DT).TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
    return SB.ToString();
}
```

I tried to use an article that is 4000 characters in length to test it. It spends 400ms to finish it.

I want to speed this up. I considered `Dictionary` or `List` may be faster, so I modified the code like this:

The Dictionary way:

```
public static List<T> d = new List<T>();

public class T 
{
    public string s;
    public string t;
}       

public static string Translate(string i)
{
    if (d.Count == 0)
    {
        foreach (char c in a)
        {
            int o = a.IndexOf(c);
            d.Add(new T() { s = c.ToString(), t = A[o].ToString() });
        }
    }
    DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in i)
    {
        var Elements = d.Where(X => X.s == c.ToString());
        if (Elements.Count() == 0)
        {
            SB.Append(c.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            SB.Append(Elements.FirstOrDefault().t);
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Time:" + (DateTime.Now - DT).TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
    return SB.ToString();
}
```

Finally, it spends about 20s to finish it, much more than using the `IndexOf` method. I tried the `Dictionary` way after that and found it wastes much more time than `List`. Obviously `Dictionary` and `List` is not the right way.

I wonder if there is any way for me to make it faster? Thank you.

Comment: instead of two strings, have you thought about using a `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary<char, char>` so you can quickly lookup the character to replace?

Comment: Why do you need a string builder?  Just use List<string>.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I tried the Dictionary way and found it waste much more time(about 26s) to finish it than the List way.

Comment: @juharr I tried the Dictionary way and found it waste much more time(about 26s) to finish it than the List way.

Comment: @jdweng Someone told me the StringBuilder can combine the character to string faster so I used it.

Comment: @MelonNG it is quite strange, can you show your dictionary attempt? What size is your "dictionary" string usually?

Comment: Are you counting the time it takes to create the `Dictionary` from your two strings?  Also how do you use it?

Comment: @GuruStron I update the code of DIctionary. It is almost the same as the List one.

Comment: I said use a `Dictioanry<char, char>` not a `Dictionary<long, T>`

Comment: Consider using `for(int c=0;c<A.count(); ++c) i.replace(A[c], a[c]);` instead. It might be faster this way.

Comment: @HirasawaYui That's going to do a lot of `Replace` calls, so it's not going to be very fast.

Comment: @juharr no, the time does not include the creating time.

Comment: The problem is that you're using the dictionry incorrectly.  You don't create a dictionary just to iterate over all the entries.  You create one with a key that you can use to quickly lookup something.  In your case using a `char` key to get another `char` would make the most sense.

Comment: @juharr I'd rather execute replace function 10 times than iterate over 4000 characters one by one.

Comment: You are not combining characters.  You are indexing into a string.   So why spend resources splitting when you are just doing indexing?

Comment: @HirasawaYui Yeah, that's an improvement over what the OP is doing, but still isn't the most optimal.

Comment: Where then Count could be a !Any. You don't need to count them all just stop when you find one. You could also call First for default and check for null.

Comment: Are there any character requirements we can use as constraints like it is only upper and lowercase alphabet plus number plus space plus typical punctuation? Or is it all if Unicode? ASCII 256 only?

Comment: @ThisClark Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try using `Dictionary<char, char>` for mapping and using char array and `string` ctor accepting one instead of `StringBuilder`:

```
static string A = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

static Dictionary<char, char> Mapped = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Select((c, i) => (c, As: A[i])).ToDictionary(x => x.c, x => x.As);

public static string Translate(string s)
{
    DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;
    var res = new char[s.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = s[i];
        if(Mapped.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            res[i] = Mapped[c];
        }
        else
        {
            res[i] = c;
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Time:" + (DateTime.Now - DT).TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
    return new string(res);
}
```

Also to benchmark this kind of code personally I prefer to use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Comment: One small opportunity for improvement: instead of the `if/else` block just say `res[i] = Mapped.TryGetValue(c, out var value) ? value : c;` It'll avoid a second lookup attempt when the value is found.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the string `a` into a dictionary with the character as the key and the mapped value from `A` as the value.

```
void Main()
{
    Translate("Hej").Dump();
}
const string A = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static Dictionary<char, char> a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                     .Select((c, i) => (c, i))
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.c, x => A[x.i]);


public string Translate(string i)
{
    DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(i.Length);
    foreach (char c in i)
    {
        if (a.TryGetValue(c, out var r))
        {
            SB.Append(r);
        }
        else
        {
            SB.Append(c.ToString());
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Time:" + (DateTime.Now - DT).TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
    return SB.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Personally I think having the dictionary just map to the replacement char instead of doing the extra step of getting an index to lookup in the other string would make more sense, but in the end this is way better than anything the OP came up with.

Comment: @juharr I agree, that is event better

Comment: @Guru Stron 's way is faster. His codes are nearly the same as yours, maybe it is because of the stringbuilder.

Comment: @MelonNG could be. Try setting the capacity of the StringBuilder to  `i.Length`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed and string `a` and `A` have the same length... Then this might be what you want.

```cs
        private static string a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        private static string A = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        public static unsafe void MakeWeirdStuff(string value)
        {
            if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            fixed (char* chr = value)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                {
                    char valueChar = *(chr + i);
                    int index = a.IndexOf(valueChar);

                    if (index >= 0)
                        *(chr + i) = A[index];
                }
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to allow unsafe code in your project and compile it in "Release" mode with optimization turned on.

Comment: Well, I think the unsafe code is faster than the original way while I learned less about C++ and dare not use it. Thanks all the same.